# Tomcat Server Thread Pool

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat7

I am using tomcat default thread pooling, kept got problems when users sign up, it simply no thread after a few days and users couldn't get a new thread, so the two step register process broke.

```
Here is the configuration for tomcat 7.0.23:

<Connector port="80" maxThreads="300" acceptCount="150" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
-->
<Context path="" docBase="mydoc" debug="1" reloadable="true"> 
       <Resource name="jdbc/DateDB" auth="Application"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://myip:3306/database?autoReconnect=true"
            username="xxxxxx"
            password="xxxxxx"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1 from dual"
    validationInterval="120000"
            initialSize="10"
            maxActive="-1"
            maxIdle="10"
    minIdle="5"
            maxWait="100" 
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            logAbandoned="true"
            />
  </context>
 ...
```

No matter how I adjust those validationQuery, interval initialSize, log, remove, max/min values, it's still run out of threads after awhile.

NO mattter how I config it, tomcat connection pool always break, no one can sign up after awhile. someone has experience how to make it working? Is the newest version has a fix?